# How can I reference CSS correctly?

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc

I wonder what's wrong with this quote:

```
<link href="/static/plugin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/plugin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In my SSM project,When I use the first piece of code, it works.

But when I use the second piece of code,it doesn't works.

P.S:bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap1.min.css are the same thing.

Comment: Have you gone into the dev tools on your browser and seen whether there are any errors showing on the console?

Comment: I see,my problem is:In Web.xml, the servlet intercepts all requests but does not use defaultServlet to allow release of static resource files